# Set of all finite sequences

Tags: terminology

Does the set of all finite sequnces contain infinite sequences? In other words the set of all $(a_{i})_{i=1..N}$ . It looks like we can construct any infinite sequence since if we want to go one index ahead we just pick the next finite etc

Comment: Just read the first sentence of your question...

Comment: Or, read your username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The set of all finite sequences contains arbitrarily long sequences.  (This means for any length of sequence an adversary demands, you can exhibit a sequence of that length in the set.)  It does not contain infinitely long sequences because, as it is defined, it does not.